# Exchange 2010 force email send over external smtp server for one specific mail adress

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, external

I have a acepted domain in my exchange server, lets call it @domain.com. I receive my mails by getting them from an external mailserver with my pop3 connector.

I have one user (lets call him user1@domain.com) which is not using his exchange account. He`s working with a local profil and receives his mails with by calling them directly with pop3 mail.

The problem is: If I want to send him a mail from a user that is using the Exchange Server the exchange server tries to deliever the mail internally but user1@domain.com has no account in the exchange server.

How can I force the exchange server to send mails to user1@domain.com over my external smtp server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the domain from authoritative to internal relay.

In the Exchange Management Console -> "Organization Configuration" -> "Hub Transport" -> "Accepted Domains" Tab -> Right click the domain in question -> "Properties" -> Internal Relay Domain.